# What happens to answer flags when their question is deleted?

Tags: discussion, flags, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

Recently I flagged an answer as "not an answer". Later on, I found my flag had been declined with the generic:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I checked out the post, and the question had been removed (for reasons of moderation, not by the owner). The answer was very clearly not an answer (it was the OP thanking all the answerers), so this, along with the generic decline, lead me to wonder, was this a simple mistake, or are flags on answers automatically declined when their question is removed?

More broadly, **what happens to answer flags when the parent question is deleted?** Are there different scenarios with different criteria?

Comment: What time was the flag cast, what time was the flag handled, and what time was the question deleted?

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure where to get that data besides flag cast (20 hours ago)

Comment: @River I think at least some of that information should be visible in the answer's timeline at: stackoverflow.com/posts/postId/timeline

Comment: @Keiwan that doesn't seem to be possible for deleted questions. I could always have a 10k+ user check the deletion time, but the key piece of information, flag handled time, seems only accessible by a moderator.

Comment: @River Your flag history shows the time the flag was cast and handled.  You'd need to link to the post for someone to know when it was deleted.

Comment: @Servy where is the "handled" time stamp? I only see the "answered" time stamp and single time stamp next to the decline reason (which I think is cast, not handled)

Comment: @River It's the tooltip for the flag status.

Comment: @Servy Oh wow! I learn new things about SO every day. That's super helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was a simple mistake, my mistake; I misclicked and should have deleted the answer instead (it was deleted from review instead).

Mea culpa.

If there are still active flags on a post when it is deleted, then those are automatically marked as helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more curious about the flags. Are they automatically handled on a question deletion or do they all need to be dealt with manually?

Comment: @River: the flag was already dealt with *before* I deleted the post. Deleting a post generally auto-marks still-active flags as helpful.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's what I assumed was the case before this hiccup made me question that assumption. Thanks!

Comment: @River Hence why I asked you to look at the deletion time relative to the time the flag was handled, as that would have shown that the flag was handled before the post was deleted.

Comment: @Servy Yes, knowing about that feature would've saved me from asking this question. Oh well.