# Need clarification regarding wrongly raised and validated spam flag

Tags: discussion, spam, specific-answer

[A recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49733811/2301450) to an old now-deleted off-topic question read

> You can also use pythonanywhere.
>
> Visit www.pythonanywhere.com to get started

As of now, its contents are not shown because it was "marked as spam or rude or abusive".

Here's what I've found:

> Contents of a post that was deleted and got at least one valid red flag, [will be hidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/). -- [*FAQ*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/260312)

> Spam flags need to be marked as helpful in order for the message to show up. -- [*Oded*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131026/remove-links-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-community-from-spam-offensive-flags/199969#comment953798_199969)

> In a case like this, we have four options: apply a hard spam flag
>   (immediately validating the flag and applying harsh penalties to the
>   user), deleting the post (validating the flag, but not applying those
>   penalties), clearing the flag (disputing it), or declining the flag. -- [*Brad Larson*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365706/2301450)

Considering the answer was deleted *along with the question*, all of this suggests that it's got a spam flag that was marked as helpful, and the poster received the aforementioned "harsh penalties", which normally include losing 100 reputation points. Is this correct?

This is important, because PythonAnywhere is a well-established service, and I can't imagine them using an 8 months old account with filled profile for promotion. The answer also *does* answer the question, and so doesn't fit any existing definitions of spam on this site.

It seems that the spam flags were raised and approved in error, and as a result the user received too severe a punishment. Can the spam flag on their post be cleared?

Comment: "it's got a spam flag that was manually validated" - validated by way of deletion, not necessarily "manually".

Comment: When users post crap answers like that then they do run the risk of them not being treated too kindly.  This is their responsibility, not ours.  Hopefully he learned a lesson.

Comment: @SFTP: ah, thanks, apparently [you're right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354492/what-happens-to-answer-flags-when-their-question-is-deleted#comment500674_354493) (took me a while to find a reference for that).  It was still wrongly validated though.

Comment: @HansPassant yeah, it was bad, but still not spam. What are the odds that it will be selected as a review audit?

Comment: @vaultah I cleared the spam flag on it - so it won't be chosen for an audit because of that...

Comment: @JonClements: thanks! :) Case closed, I guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I handled the flag, by adding the last close vote and then deleting the answer, thus, validating the flag.

Jon Clements then cleared all spam flags, as the answer wasn't spam, so it wouldn't be used as an spam audit, which meant the answer was automatically undeleted and then he needed to redelete it. This way the flag was disputed.

The system will automatically delete orphan answers (undeleted) to deleted questions.

Comment: I need a coffee before editing this

Comment: Wasn't that answer deleted the same moment as the question? And I think it was Jon who cleared the flags (see the comments) after I posted this question. Am I missing something?

Comment: @vaultah I cleared the flags, which undeleted the answer. I didn't realise the answer was visible after deleting the question. Which is why Jon then deleted the answer a second time. Clearing spam flags causes the post to be undeleted. The system would have auto deleted it, being on a deleted question- but it's something new I've learnt along the way.

Comment: I can only see two deletion-related actions in the answer history/timeline: undeletion by Jon (automatic, by clearing the flags) and deletion by Jon (because the answer was visible, even though the question was deleted). Also, if the flags were disputed, why were the contents of the answer hidden?

Comment: @vaultah added a screen shot to show you what I can see. As for the contents being hidden, I'm guessing because the flag wasn't declined. I'll ping Jon into this thread to verify this.

Comment: @vaultah the clearing flags thing is not entirely intuitive - it effectively re-writes history and it gets more awkward to read the timeline about what happened - it really does look like you did something you may not have... :)

Comment: @vaultah turns out the history for the question is unreliable in that it is overwritten - I've updated my answer. Sorry for the mess about

Comment: Thanks all, that clears it up. Did you mean to write "automatically undeleted"?

Comment: @vaultah yep thanks for that *mod with training wheels*

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that the user didn't really have any reputation to *lose*, per se.  [Their activity indicates this.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8445687/abdoul?tab=topactivity)

In this regard I'd think that...well...this was an ill-fated attempt at a link-only answer.  It itself didn't seem spammy - didn't have the same *texture* as spam here - but by virtue of the post being deleted, the flag itself was probably resolved as "correct".

My gut feeling is simple:  it probably *shouldn't* have been resolved like this.  Perhaps a moderator can reach out to them and explain that link-only answers aren't The Right Thing™ to do?

Comment: Brad's quote (in the OP) says that simply deleting a post with a pending spam flag will mark the flag as helpful, but __not__ apply the penalties.