# Is it a good idea that flagged content goes helpful when its question gets deleted?

Tags: discussion, helpful-flags

According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354492/what-happens-to-answer-flags-when-their-question-is-deleted):

> If there are still active flags on a post when it is deleted, then those are automatically marked as helpful.

... my understanding is: if there is a question that has 2 delete votes already, one could theoretically go in and flag comments or answers to then quickly give the third delete vote on the question, and turn all flags into *helpful*. I assume: the flagged folks would never notice, only the "helpful flags" counter of the person doing this goes up.

So people only interested in pimping their "helpful flags" counter could misuse the system here easily.

Is my interpretation correct? But then, in reality, this isn't a problem, because nobody starts "cheating" for the "helpful flags" count?

Comment: What sort of scenario do you envision where this is a problem?

Comment: That's not always the case. If the flags are on the post (rather than comments) and they're custom flags, they aren't handled when a post is deleted.

Comment: *Oh boy, I'm busted ...*

Comment: Looking at your helpful flags count you really didn't exploit this loophole ... that is good.

Comment: @rene I was tempted when I 2 "deletes" on such a question, where I had a delete vote / flag (rightfully so) on one of the answers already ... you see, there was another answer there which I could have flagged ... that tempting lasted for like 0.2 seconds. Then I thought for a few seconds if I should do it, just to test my hypothesis. I finally decided to do some research and then write this question instead.

Comment: I've seen worse things been done "for science" ...

Comment: I have been tempted to flag VLQ on questions with 4 close votes, and then immediately cast the last close vote, since closure automatically marks VLQ flags as *helpful*, and otherwise I have gotten a fair number of VLQ declined flags in the past.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of really weird ways to game this if you're the *owner of the post*... Those might be worth addressing.

Otherwise though... You have 10K rep at least, and you have to wait for two other people to vote. Yes, you inflate your "helpful flags" count - that and $2 will buy you a Starbucks coffee.

Well... Ok. You can earn some badges if you keep it up long enough. And 10 helpful flags earn you another 1 flag per day, up to a maximum of 100 flags / day... So if you do this on 10 posts (or raise two flags each on 5 posts) you, the 10K user, can earn... 1 more flag tomorrow. If you really work at it, you can hit the limit of 100 flags per day slightly faster than you would be able to otherwise, which might help you hit those badges a little faster.

...that's assuming a moderator doesn't catch on and start declining flags; that'll slow you down, especially if you get flag-banned for a while. This auto-helpful thing doesn't apply to "other" flags either, so no padding your stats with piles of them.

The abuse potential is pretty limited, really. Most folks I've seen do this tend to stick to flags that actually make sense: "not an answer" or "very low quality" on posts that are getting deleted for being... Well, not answers and/or low quality. Frankly, if you want to vote to delete and then flag to get more eyes on the problem, that's probably useful. Throw in a downvote too if it's that bad.

Worst-case... You find a way to rack up thousands of completely bogus flags that've done no one any good, a mod stumbles onto your flag history, notifies the team, we hard-delete all of it, and you've just wasted a lot of time and didn't even get that cup of coffee.

Comment: ... and the chance that a 10K user doesn't already have max/more than enough daily flags? Seems kinda low.

Comment: probably worth noting that flags are throttled at one in 5 seconds, meaning there is a real risk that moderator who happens to be around to quickly pay attention to first or second flag in the series will have plenty time to decline most of the flags before abuser hits that delete link - which in turn can easily trigger flag suspension

Answer (score 3):

I think I see your point:  a user would be gaming the system in a sense to try and get more "helpful" points.

I'm not sure of the viability since a question with *n-1* delete votes can survive for an indefinite amount of time before it's *actually* deleted from the site, thus resolving the flags.

My gut tells me that there are systems in place which *already* check for anomalous flagging, so a user who attempted to game the system in this fashion would likely not get very far before it rising to the attention of moderators.

Comment: @GhostCat:  There are a lot of questions which linger with almost all of the delete votes necessary to remove it.  Many of these are questions which *exceed* the typical 3 delete votes for removal, and my answer didn't make that point clear, which I'll fix.  There's no guarantee that those questions will get moderated at *any* point in the future.