# Only dismiss custom moderator flags when a moderator explicitly marks them helpful or declined

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, custom-flags

#### TL;DR

Custom moderator flags should only be dismissed by a moderator explicitly marking them helpful or declined. I raised a custom moderator flag on a question. The flag was automatically marked helpful when the question was closed by a mod, without displaying the custom flag to any moderator. This resulted in no moderator seeing the flag while it was active.

---

#### Longer explanation

I recently raised a custom flag on this question about an erroneous reopening of a duplicate question and later casting a close vote with an incorrect reason by a gold-badger; see the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63726215/timeline).

I realized that although my flag is marked as helpful no action has been taken accordingly. Upon discussing it with the moderator who has handled that question (not the flag), I realized that they have never seen my flag. Apparently, as they were reviewing the CV queue, they came across this question and decided to close it which resulted in automatically marking my flag as helpful.

Custom flags can be used for various cases, like when there are multiple abusive comments or other problematic behaviors on the post (e.g. a user who posts spam regularly). Automatically marking them as helpful when the question gets closed or deleted is not the right way to handle them.

At first, I thought showing the flag to the moderators alongside the queue would be a helpful feature but on second thoughts I reckon these flags should be handled separately by a moderator and not as part of any other queue and certainly not automatically by the system.

I doubt that this is by design and think that this is a side-effect of marking other types of flags (like closing flags by users below 3k rep) as helpful when the question is closed.

---

If you believe otherwise, please elaborate; if this is indeed a bug, then an immediate fix is necessary as it would undermine moderators' decisions and moderation of the site in general.

Comment: @CertainPerformance https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/50409252

Comment: @CertainPerformance I confirm M--'s custom mod-flag was marked as helpful simultaneously with the moderator closing the question from the review queue, and that I've seen another custom mod-flag be marked helpful on another question as a direct result of me closing that other question. On that other question, when the flag was marked helpful, closing was the only only action I'd taken on the question (and no other moderator is listed as having acted on that question/flag). I know this, because I'd specifically planned on leaving a message when clearing the flag.

Comment: If the flag gets dismissed without being seen, that really doesn't sound like how things should be. Does the marking of the flag as helpful also remove it from the mod queue? If so, that's a problem

Comment: Same with deletion, which also marks all including custom flags helpful.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, the flag which M-- raised was removed from the mod queue when it was marked helpful as a result of a moderator closing the question. As far as I know, the only reason a moderator saw the flag was that M-- mentioned in chat their frustration with the action they thought had been taken as a result of the flag.

Comment: @SamuelLiew [Comment flags are automatically deemed helpful if the parent post (Q or A) is deleted; this allows for abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280413) and [Is it a good idea that flagged content goes helpful when its question gets deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370224)

Comment: @adiga yes, I am aware of those you linked

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this! The closing functionality has been modified to make this work a little better.

When a question is closed, custom flags are no longer automatically marked as resolved. The moderator interface shows the flags at the bottom of the screen, which was easily missed. Moderators will need to mark each custom flag on a closed post as helpful or declined.

However, when a question is closed from the moderator dashboard, the flag will automatically be marked as resolved. On the moderator dashboard, it's much harder to miss a custom flag since it's shown right underneath the relevant post. Here, we will assume that the custom flag was seen and the custom flags will continue to be marked as resolved automatically.

Comment: What is the *actual* criteria that is used to differentiate between a closure which clears custom flags and one which doesn't? Basically, there are a lot of userscripts around which send close-votes. It would be nice to know for sure what the difference is, so that it can be avoided or activated, as desired. Obviously, we can reverse engineer it, but it would save time and be more assured if we just know.

Comment: It's just looking at the `Referer` header to see if it came from `/admin/dashboard`. Anything sent with that header will automatically resolve custom flags. Anything without that header will keep custom flags unresolved. Hopefully this means that userscripts will default to keeping custom flags open _unless_ they're requests sent from the admin dashboard. If this is inconvenient, I can look at adding some kind of parameter in the URL params or request body instead.

Comment: Personally, I don't desire for custom flags to be automatically marked helpful from the mod dashboard (or anywhere). If I'm handling a custom flag, then closing the question is usually just one of the steps I'm taking in response to the flag. IIRC, having the custom flag auto-resolved clears the flag and removes the post from view in the dashboard. Normally, I'll still have things I'm wanting to do with the post, so I have to go hunting in my mod-/action-history to find the post again. (continued)

Comment: In addition, I'll often want to leave a comment with marking the flag helpful, which the auto-resolve makes impossible, unless I remember to open the question in another tab in order to first mark it helpful, then do whatever I need to do. In fact, I first noticed that the auto-resolve existed when questions unexpectedly disappeared from the mod-dashboard when I closed them.

Comment: OTOH, this change is quite beneficial as it results in resolving the primary issue of resolving custom flags without the possibility of a moderator seeing the custom flag, which was the case when a moderator is acting on questions in any of the normal review queues (where flags are not shown in the UI).

Comment: As I'm thinking about this, I realized this solution results in there being a race condition where a custom flag could be raised after the mod-dashboard is loaded, but before the mod closes the Q. Loading the mod-dashboard page can be considerably prior to handling flags on any particular question/answer, given that there could easily be many other posts handled first from the same page without reloading (and new flags are not displayed dynamically). The amount of time between loading a mod-dashboard page and resolving the last flags on that page can easily be 10s of minutes (or even hours).

Comment: Regarding your question about implementation (i.e. `Referer` header vs. parameter): Either will work from the point of view of userscripts, but a parameter is easier. Using a parameter potentially requires you to make modifications to multiple parts of the frontend JavaScript, which may be a bit more effort, but does allow you to have it be an active choice in your code, rather than just which page originates the request. Userscripts can intercept the AJAX call to strip or set either the `Referer` or a parameter, with parameters a bit easier. So, a userscript can be written either way.

Comment: On thing I'd like to see fixed here (because this is kinda clunky as-is) is that the dashboard removes anything you act on, even if that action didn't handle the flag. Where I see this being confusing is that this will **increase** the likelihood that a flag won't get handled correctly because the interface will (unintuitively) still hide the post if I merely close the question. I know this because I handle a fair number of red flags where the question needs closure but the red flag needs a decline. If I close it from the mod interface it still hides it

Comment: I am not a moderator so I don't have any experience interacting with the dashboard, but after reading what these other M guys :) said, I think letting mods decide what to do with custom flags regardless of how and from where they are handling a question is the best option. However, this is definitely a step forward. Thank you.

Comment: A sincere thanks for the feedback @M-- and @Machavity! Your particular suggestions are out of scope for this specific issue of moderators not seeing custom flags. We’d still love to see more bug/feature-requests created based on your feedback on other issues you’re facing — although I can’t guarantee we’ll always be able to prioritize all of these, they will generally be in line with [the “improving tooling and automation for growth” core area in our roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/).