# Is there any action moderators can take to stop a user from posting the same comment on all the questions they answer?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags

I found a comment under a question:

> Does my answer answer your question?

From a user that added an answer to said question.

I noticed that the comment was posted at almost the same time as the answer, so I commented to tell the user that it wasn't necessary to add that comment immediately after answering, as OP is notified of your answer. I flagged the comment as NLN and moved along.

A couple of minutes later another user pointed out that this user did that on every question they answered. And, lo and behold, it was true!

And since then that user has posted another four answers, all with that comment.

The icing on the cake is that on the last one I flagged the comment, it got deleted and they posted it again.

Is there any action that can be taken to avoid this user creating useless and frankly annoying comments?

Comment: Nothing that we normal users can do. A mod on the other hand... **who you can contact with a mod flag on one of said comments**, could potentially do something.

Comment: @KevinB so next time, instead of flagging as no longer needed I should flag as "something else" and explain the situation, correct? On that note, can mods see those previously deleted comments to verify I'm not telling stories?

Comment: If you think it's a case that warrants mod intervention, yes. though i suspect that if enough of these comments are flagged a mod would eventually intervene anyway, if it is indeed a problematic behavior

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I believe mods can see deleted comments.

Comment: Have you tried pinging them several times? If they don't listen even after that, then mod flag is the correct way to go.

Comment: @10Rep I'll try if I see that comment again.

Comment: Mods can talk to the user and ask them to stop, but you need to inform mods about it and clearly explain why you think this is an issue that they should deal with. It's hardly an offence that requires suspension but it's up to moderators who will review this case and decide on the best course of action.

Comment: There used to be a comment filter about stuff like this, although I don't know if this particular text would have been caught.

Comment: How about asking people to include that type of question in their answer and not in a comment? Too much moderation can scare people away.

Comment: The cited example doesn't belong in answers, either. Please do not advise people to repost it there. Just flag the comments for a moderator to delete. Stack Overflow is a moderated site. I can't see why that would scare people away. Most of our users are attracted to this site precisely *because* it is heavily moderated to keep down the noise. @SJacks

Comment: @DaveNewton The comment filter is still alive and well, but it is quite feeble, being based merely on a regular expression pattern. It certainly wouldn't have caught this. The regex pattern also isn't really extensible anymore, so we have no way of improving it to catch things like this in the future. Your best course of action is simply to let a moderator know using a flag.

Comment: What does NLN mean?

Comment: @Pavel No Longer Needed.

Comment: @CodyGray Citation Needed?  I'm not sure most of the users are attracted directly because its heavily moderated. Most of the time I'm here because of search and then distracted into reading stuff I don't need.

Comment: Who is this mysterious user?

Comment: @AkibAzmain I don't want to start a witch hunt. Also, they apparently got the message.

Comment: @CodyGray that's a valid point. A clean well presented site is easier to navigate and we all want this. What I meant is the addition of automated comment filters will no doubt put off new users so manual moderation seems a better way of handling things.

Comment: I don't see this as a real problem. I see it as a gentle reminder to the OP that they should mark a one of the answers as accepted -- a reminder some OP's need. That said, I agree the prompt is a little useless and redundant, and therefore distracting clutter, if it's given within seconds of posting an answer, in which case it just sounds greedy.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Can we *stop* them from just making comments? No. There's no such thing as a comment suspension.

Raising a mod flag on one of the **posts** (with links to other posts doing that) are preferred. Comment flags here are clunky. We would probably send a private message and ask them nicely to stop. If they didn't, we have regular suspension (no more comments or posts of any kind).

Answer (score 36):

This kind of behavior may well be reported to a moderator. Flag one of the user's answers (yes, answers) for moderator attention and explain the situation, especially that it has happened multiple times and appears to be persistent.

Flagging the comment is not recommended here, because it is automatically resolved once the comment is removed. *Whenever* you wish for the moderator to take *additional* action over something, you should prefer flagging a related post.

Don't fear to be giving moderators more trouble. It definitely sounds better to tell someone to stop posting those comments, than to have to handle a "no longer needed" flag for each answer that the user posts over time.

Comment: Flags on comments are marked helpful if the comment is deleted ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401042/1364007)). Flags on posts are not. If the custom flag was raised on a "Does my answer answer your question?" comment and the comment deleted before a moderator sees it the flag will be marked helpful but nothing will be done.

Comment: Funny that the account reporter answerd a question about reportiing ones account.

Comment: @10Rep E_net4 is my name, and reporting accounts is my game.

Comment: @E_net4isbeingimpersonated Maybe not anymore, after you've been impersonated :D

Comment: @Spectric I chose to settle an agreement with the impostor this time.