# If I flag a question for moderator attention, and it subsequently gets deleted by the poster, will moderators still look at it?

Tags: discussion, flags, deleted-questions, moderators

I'm actually purposefully not going to go into details here, so hopefully, you will still read this question even if it is specifically devoid of details.

Let's say the following happens:

1. A question is asked
2. I start commenting on the meaning and validity of the question
3. The OP responds but doesn't exactly make this clearer
4. Points 2 and 3 go back and forth for a while in the comments
5. Someone I would consider legit/legible/trustworthy on the site responds that this is a known troll, and the comments are exactly what the person is after
6. A few more comments. I then flag the question for moderator attention to ascertain whether the person is, as is commented, known for trolling
7. The question is deleted

My question is simple: Will my flag still be processed? Will some moderator still look at the question and make up their own mind whether this is a known troll trolling for some kind of response? Or will the deletion of the question remove it from the queue completely and thus leave the OP "free" to continue their trolling?

To be fair, I don't really care about the question I'm thinking of, I'm more concerned if the person is allowed to post questions on the site if their chief purpose is just to garner attention.

Bear in mind that I don't necessarily know or agree with whether this was a trolling attempt, all I know is that a post was made, I could not clearly ascertain the purpose of the question with multiple back and forth comments with the OP, before that trustworthy person chimed in.

So basically, what happened to this question?

- It was deleted, no longer eligible for anything
- It will be processed by a moderator at some point

Comment: Custom "in need of moderator intervention" flags will *always* be seen by a moderator, eventually, even if the post is deleted. If you've expressed your concerns clearly in the flag, it will be handled, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: The flag was already processed before you posted this Meta question. :-) But, yes, even in the general case, custom moderator flags are always seen and handled (eventually) by moderators, even if the question is deleted, whether that deletion is by the original poster or by the community.

Comment: @CodyGray Unless.. the post is closed, no? Then the flag goes away.. I seem to have misremembered. [Only dismiss custom moderator flags when a moderator explicitly marks them helpful or declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401042/only-dismiss-custom-moderator-flags-when-a-moderator-explicitly-marks-them-helpf) shows this issues as status-completed.

Comment: It can still reason some mod intervention. For example, in the case of insulting communication, the deletedness of the post is no-issue (in practice, mods tend to be more lenient if the post became own-deleted, but nothing obligates them for that).